# How merge events in fullcalendar on select/drag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I have fullcalendar with agendaweek view. I have events in table coming from server. I want to do the next thing: user can select few events in the table with `select` event and when he do it, I want to add green border over selected area. 
http://prntscr.com/lhkp9y

I found one way - it is to merge selected events into one, but it is not so easy if starting point is over existing event. On the screen starting point - is empty timeslot. 

What I have now: If events are `editable:false` in the table, and I start to select and starting point is over existing event, nothing happens. If starting point is - empty timeslot, it works

If events are `editable:true` in the table, and I start to select and starting point - is existing event, this event stick to cursor and start to move which is not good. I want existing event stay on the same place.

Here is my calendar code

```
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
                firstDay: 1,
                navLinks: false,
                header: false,
                selectable: true,
                eventOverlap: true,
                selectOverlap: function (event) {
                    // check is allowed to select next timeslot ot not
                    return !event.closed;
                },
                selectHelper: true,
                allDaySlot: true,
                minTime: self.minTime,
                maxTime: self.maxTime,
                slotLabelInterval: '00:30:00',
                viewSubSlotLabel: true,
                slotLabelFormat: 'h:mm a',
                editable: true,
                events: events,
                select: function (start, end, jsEvent, view) {

                    // merge selected events into one
                    self.mergeEvents();
                },
                eventDragStart: function (event, jsEvent, ui, view) {
                    // I WANT TO CANCEL DRAG, BUT IT DOESNT WORK
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Comment: "user can select few events in the table with select event"...that's not how the select event works - it's for selecting a period of time in which to create a new event. It does not enable you to select an existing event.

Comment: You can possibly use "select" to do what you want, as long as the user starts by selecting an empty space. Then you can look at the selected time period, and check fullCalendar's [existing event list](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/clientEvents) to see if any events overlap it (by examining their start and end times). Then you can delete those events and create one single event to cover that time period. But if the user starts by clicking an existing event, this will trigger "eventClick" (for a short click) or start a drag operation (if they hold the button longer, and "editable" is true)

Answer (score 0):

Try it, hope it's fine for you.

```
select: function (start, end, jsEvent, view) 
{
    var diffmin = (new Date(end).getTime()/1000 - new Date(start).getTime()/1000)/60;
    var title = diffmin+' min';
    var eventData;
    // some users click 1 slot, then the following, so we have 2 events each 30 min instead of 60 min
    // merge both events into one
    var eventmerge = false;
    $.each(allevents, function( index, eventitem )
    {
        if(eventitem!==null && typeof eventitem != 'undefined')
        {
            // if start time of new event (2nd slot) is end time of existing event (1st slot)
            if( moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm') == moment(eventitem.end).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm') )
            {
                eventmerge = true;
                // existing event gets end data of new merging event
                eventitem.end = end;
            }
            // if end time of new event (1st slot) is start time of existing event (2nd slot)
            else if( moment(end).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm') == moment(eventitem.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm') )
            {
                eventmerge = true;
                // existing event gets start data of new merging event
                eventitem.start = start;
            }

            if(eventmerge)
            {
                // recalculate
                var diffmin = (new Date(eventitem.end).getTime()/1000 - new Date(eventitem.start).getTime()/1000)/60;
                eventitem.title = diffmin+' min';

                // copy to eventData
                eventData = eventitem;

                // find event object in calendar
                var eventsarr = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');
                $.each(eventsarr, function(key, eventobj) { 
                    if(eventobj._id == eventitem.id) {
                        console.log('merging events');
                        eventobj.start = eventitem.start;
                        eventobj.end = eventitem.end;
                        eventobj.title = eventitem.title;
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', eventobj);
                    }
                });

                // break each loop
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
    if(!eventmerge)
    {
        // console.log('adding event id: '+eventcount);
        eventData = {
            id: eventcount, // identifier
            title: title,
            start: start,
            end: end,
            color: '#00AA00',
            editable: true,
            eventDurationEditable: true,
        };

        // register event in array
        allevents[eventcount] = eventData;
        eventcount++;

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true);
    }

    // console.log(start, end);
    setTimePrice(eventData);

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
},
```